# Blazor UnitTest case failing

Tags: localization, blazor-webassembly, xunit.net

I have a balzor webassembly project with localization and globalization, for which I have write test cases. some test cases are failing due to some reason. can anyone help me to figure out the issue.

[Stack trace:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICTEZ.png)

[my test case is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdoOu.png)